# Xamarin iOS applicationWillEnterForeground should call an viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have two viewController in my Xamarin.iOS app:
- loginViewController
- mainViewController

On every start or resuming the user have to login. 
I think I have to use the WillEnterForeground function in the AppDelegate.cs.

But how can I call there the ViewController?

```
RootViewController root = new RootViewController(application.Handle)
Window = new UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
Window.RootViewController = root;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

That is all I found on my internetresearches..

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController to control the navigation mecanism?

Comment: @HenriqueBarros Yes I do. UINavgationController -> LoginController -> MainController

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a **UINavigationController** to control the navigation of your app, at **WillEnterForeground** you could call:

```
this.Window.RootViewController.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

Considering the fact that a UINavigationController is your root view controller.

Comment: If I won't use a UINavigationController? How can the problem be solved otherwise?

Comment: You would have to use storyboard segues and control the flow using PerformSegue method, but you would have a lot more work.

Comment: but why wouldn't you use a UINavigationController?

Comment: I want to separate it clearly. The two ViewControllers shouldn't be connected this way.

Comment: Hmm.. I see, so what you could do is forget about the segues and on the applicationWillEnterForeground do this:

   var loginViewController = Window.RootViewController.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("your_login_view_controller_id");
   Window.RootViewController = loginViewController;

Comment: Sadly I just get a white screen and no views will be shown.

Comment: make sure you did set your view controller's id in the storyboard